# add plugin to gradle buildscript from a local jar

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'd like to apply the `google-services` Gradle plugin to a Java project from a local jar, such that my build does not need to connect to jcenter to download the plugin.

I have downloaded the `google-services-3.0.0.jar`, but I don't know how to tell gradle to load the plugin from the file.

This is my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' <---i have the jar

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to add the plugin from the jar by adding the jar in my lib folder and call it from the project gradle dependencies like so :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'app/libs')
        classpath files('app/libs/google-services-3.0.0.jar')

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the same line but still my Apply plugin is not resolved,  Can you please suggest something

Comment: not only you need to add the line also the the jar should be placed correctly inside app/libs or any dir you find suitable

Answer (score 6):

You should create a directory with your `*.jar` libs and add `flatDir {}` in `repositories {}` block to initialize the directory that keeps jar-libs as a repository:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir { dirs 'jarlibs' } // *.jar libs are keep in 'app/jarlibs' dir
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' // now it works
    }
}
```