# How to add a Gradle plugin from the file system?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I need to use a Gradle plugin that I have as a jar. It's not coming from a remote repository. What's the correct way to use it? Add it as a dependency? Could somebody please illustrate how this should be done? Thanks!

Comment: see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40821215/6899896

Comment: How does this apply to plugins?